# How Can i Show multiple location marker with optimize Distance and draw line to connect each others

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-studio-3.0

I have already try to achieve this type of functionality using google map direction API. You can see the picture I found this in javascript code but I want to do in android.

[I want to achieve like this please click here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L0pJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
PolygonOptions rectOptions2;
```

rectOptions2= new PolygonOptions();
     mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onMapClick( final LatLng latLng)
                {
//                    PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
//                            .add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
//                    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
                    // Creating a marker
                    BitmapDescriptor icon = 
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map);
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions .icon(icon);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        final  List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                        if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                           markerOptions.title(location);
                            location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                            latitude=latLng.latitude;
                            longitude=latLng.longitude;
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//                    mMap.clear();
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    lat=latitude;
                    lng=longitude;
                    rectOptions2.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                                        polygon= mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions2);
                    polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
                    polygon.setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
                //add lat and lng in arraylist here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi umesh this is draw polyline without shortest route from source to destination.